# Conflicting jQuery click events for navigation menu of responsive site

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I am implementing a mobile navigation menu and I want to capture the click event on the non-menu area in order to close the menu.

```
//#1 click event - opening menu when user clicks on button
$('.mobile-menu-toggler').on('click', function(){
   $('.navi-mobile').addClass('nav-mobile-open');
   $('.site-page').addClass('site-page-open');
});

//#2 click event - hide menu when user clicks on outside nav
$(document).on('click', function(e){
    var obj = $('.navi-mobile')
    var nav_open = obj.hasClass('nav-mobile-open');
    var ext = (e.target == obj[0]);

    if (nav_open && !ext) {
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log('hide menu')
    }
});
```

The problem is that event #2 gets fired at the same time as #1 when the user opens the nav. And the conditions in #2 are allowing the hide action to take place.

Comment: `$('.mobile-menu-toggler').on('click', function(e){ e.stopPropagation(); ...`  http://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/

Comment: It is a menu, if you stop the propagation, are you sure that the links in this menu will still be clickable ?

Comment: @Flo-Schield-Bobby Yes, because it stops bubbling up, not down. Links inside the menu would be down.

Comment: You're right, it effectively works : http://jsfiddle.net/s7DxN/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One valid approach is to prevent the effect of #2 when the event #1 is fired. You can do it using stopPropagation function in #1

```
//#1 click event - opening menu when user clicks on button
$('.mobile-menu-toggler').on('click', function(e){
   e.stopPropagation();
   $('.navi-mobile').addClass('nav-mobile-open');
   $('.site-page').addClass('site-page-open');
});
```

Also you can check if the clicked dom element has a parent with class nav-mobile-open, and stop the event if this condition is true.

```
var nav_open = obj.hasClass('nav-mobile-open');
if(obj.parents('.nav-mobile-open').length) nav_open = true;
```

Regards.

## **jQuery .stopPropagation Documentation**

Comment: `preventDefault` is not necessary

Comment: Unless op has something funky with HTML, this only correct answer here! lol

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a stopPropagation() function to your document.click declaration

```
//#2 click event - hide menu when user clicks on outside nav
$(document).on('click', function(e){

    e.stopPropagation(); // HERE

    var  obj = $('.navi-mobile')
    var nav_open = obj.hasClass('nav-mobile-open');
    var ext = (e.target == obj[0]);

    if (nav_open && !ext) {
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log('hide menu')
    }
});
```

[here](http://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/)'s a link for more info

Comment: Shouldn't it be in the $('.mobile-menu-toggler') click handler instead of the document click handler ?

Comment: Prob with stopProp on `document` is that there's nothing to bubble up to other than window. Though it might be noted, `document` is treated quite differently in Chrome and FF than it is in IE, which is a prob with assigning click directly to document. And dif ver of IE are dif from each other on how they treat document. Best to move an overall click func like this to either `window` or `$('html')`